# Excel VBA - errors with application.worksheetfunction.match

Tags: excel, vba

I'm really losing my mind with this so would appreciate anyone taking the time to help!

I suspect my problems stem from incorrect variable declaration but I haven't been able to work it out.

So why does this test procedure work:

```
Sub testmatch3()

    Dim arr()           As Variant
    Dim num             As Long
    Dim searchVal       As Variant
    Dim i               As Long

    ReDim arr(1 To 10)

    For i = 1 To 10
        arr(i) = i
    Next i

    searchVal = 4
    Debug.Print getMatch(searchVal, arr)

End Sub

Function getMatch(valueToMatch As Variant, matchArr As Variant) As Long

    getMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(valueToMatch, matchArr, 0)

End Function
```

But the following gives me a mismatch error (Type 13):

```
Sub NewProcedure()

    Dim ENVarr              As Variant
    Dim StageRange          As Range
    Dim cell                As Range
    Dim LastRow             As Long
    Dim i                   As Long
    Dim ConnSheet           As Worksheet
    Dim tempstring          As Variant
    Dim arr()               As Variant

    Set ConnSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("L1 forces")

    ' Find the last used row in the sheet and define the required ranges
    LastRow = ConnSheet.Range("A11").End(xlDown).row
    Set StageRange = ConnSheet.Range("H11:H" & LastRow)

    ' I have a big table of data in the "ENV sheet" which I transfer into a large 2D array
    ENVarr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ENV").Range("A6").CurrentRegion

    ' From the ENVarray, make its second column into a new 1D array
    ' This new array has an upper bound dimension equal to the number of rows in ENVarr
    ReDim arr(LBound(ENVarr, 1) To UBound(ENVarr, 1))
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i) = ENVarr(i, 2)
    Next i

    tempstring = "1140"
    Debug.Print getMatch(tempstring, arr)

End Sub

Function getMatch(valueToMatch As Variant, matchArr As Variant) As Long

    getMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(valueToMatch, matchArr, 0)

End Function
```

Just to note the value "1140" DEFINITELY exists in arr!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in your sheet is the number 1140 and you try to match the string "1140". Did you try to write

```
tempstring = 1140
```

without quotes?

Alternatively: make sure that there is really a string in your excel sheet: `="1140"` and it is not only formatted as string. The return value of `=TYPE(cell)` ('cell' is containing your 1140) has to be `2`.